# Intellij IDEA not showing Typescript option under Create New Step definition File (Protractor, Cucumber)

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, protractor, cucumber

Project : Protractor Cucumber and Typescript
IDE : Intellij IDEA Ultimate edition

[image]

Please suggest me what I am missing.

I have added the following plugins:

1.Javascript Support
2.Node.js

[image]

Comment: What IDEA version do you use? Works fine for me in 2020.1.*, I can choose between *TypeScript* and *JavaScript*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see from your screenshots, you are using some old IDE version. Support for Cucumber steps defined using TypeScript is provided since 2019.3. Please consider upgrading to the most recent IDEA version